# shinyproxy cannot login with default user and password

Tags: shinyproxy

I'm new with ShinyProxy, and I followed this [tutorial](https://www.shinyproxy.io/getting-started/), the web shows correctly.

However, I cannot login with user name as **tesla** or **jack** and password as **password**.
And the error message in the log is as below:

```
ERROR 34460 --- [XNIO-2 task-17]
w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred
while trying to authenticate the user.
```

[image]

My `applicaion.yml` is as below:

```
proxy:
  title: Open Analytics Shiny Proxy
  logo-url: http://www.openanalytics.eu/sites/www.openanalytics.eu/themes/oa/logo.png
  landing-page: /
  heartbeat-rate: 10000
  heartbeat-timeout: 60000
  port: 8080
  authentication: ldap
  admin-groups: scientists
  # Example: 'simple' authentication configuration
  users:
  - name: jack
    password: password
    groups: scientists
  - name: tesla
    password: password
    groups: mathematicians
  # Example: 'ldap' authentication configuration
  ldap:
    url: ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com
    user-dn-pattern: uid={0}
    group-search-base:
    group-search-filter: (uniqueMember={0})
    manager-dn: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
    manager-password: password
  # Docker configuration
  docker:
    cert-path: /home/none
    url: http://localhost:2375
    port-range-start: 20000
  specs:
  - id: 01_hello
    display-name: Hello Application
    description: Application which demonstrates the basics of a Shiny app
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    access-groups: [scientists, mathematicians]
  - id: 06_tabsets
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_06_tabsets()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    access-groups: scientists

logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

Answer (score 6):

Change: `authentication: ldap`

for: `authentication: simple`

Comment: please explain briefly how this is done

Comment: Just update the yaml file line 8 on the above example